# Clang-Tidy: Redundant 'operator<<' declaration

Tags: c++, templates, clang-tidy

I was trying to write a friend operator<< to my class and I got this warning of redundant. And can't figure how to fix it.

Thank you in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class  T>
class test
{
public:
    explicit test(T a)  noexcept : m_{ a } {}
    template <class Y>

    //line below shows that warning.
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const test<Y>& lhs);
private:
    T m_;
};

template<class Y>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const test<Y>& lhs)
{
    out << lhs.m_ << endl;
    return out;
}


int main()
{
    test<int>    p {25};
    test<double> q {17.5};

    std::cout << "By Friend " << p;
    std::cout << "By Friend " << q;
    return 0;
}
```

***Edit 1***
    //Removed template Y from the operator<< int he class declaration

```
template<class  T>
class test
{
public:
    explicit test(T a)  noexcept : m_{ a } {}
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream&, const test<T>&);
private:
    T m_;
};

template<class T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const test<T>& lhs)
{
    out << lhs.m_ << endl;
    return out;
}
```

now I got a Warning

> warning: friend declaration 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const test&)' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]

PS : in Visual Studio I got Error Links

***EDIT 1.2***  //edit done for `EDIT 1`

I changed the Edit 1 as follow :

```
....
friend std::ostream& operator<< <> (std::ostream&, const test<T>&);
....
```

So warnings and error links are resolved.

Comment: No warnings on godbolt with -Wall and clang trunk.

Comment: Can you show the actual warning?

Comment: So it's clang-tidy, and not clang? What rule triggers this?

Comment: @Useless : the actual warning says : Clang-Tidy: Redundant 'operator<<' declaration in the operator<< funct declared in the class

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher : Tags updated ;)

Comment: Why is the friend declaration templated with a different template type? Can't you omit that altogether?

Comment: @paddy : it is the case where all friend template instanciations are friend with all class template instansiation.

Edit : So I removed the templated Y and I got a warning `warning: friend declaration 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const test<T>&)' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]`

Comment: Have you tried removing `template <class Y>` from the class declaration? (Use T instead of Y at the implementation)

Comment: @JVApen : Please look at Edit 1 (hope did what you meant)

Comment: @JVApen : after all had to add <> in after the operator<<  and befor the args.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd - An answer belongs in the answer section, not as an edit.

Comment: @StoryTeller: My question was about the many - to -many version of friend template to class template. The version in Edit 1 is one-to-one template to template. So the Cling Tidy redundant warning still didn't get resolved. Or may be  the one suggested by JVApen works for many to many too.

Comment: And what is `EDIT 2` if not an answer to resolve all warnings and errors?

Comment: That was for the errors got from Edit 1. may be I should rename it to Edit 1.2

Comment: So is this actually resolved, or did it just fix some problems and leave others?

Comment: @Useless: did not fix the redundant warning message. If there is way to resolve or understand it.